# Arrays vs. JSON

Tags: php, json

Which is better **in PHP**?  Drew Wilson implies that arrays are hardly worth dealing with if possible: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/an-introduction-to-json

Would it be wise of me to create all my future web apps with this in mind?

Comment: There is no versus between them !!

Comment: Even the links says: "Not a good comparison since JSON can have arrays inside of it" Actualy it's not a good comparison for a different reason.

Comment: Isn't json really an array, just that it will always be a certain structure?

Comment: You simply can't compare two entirely different data structures. They serve different purposes. It's like asking,"which is better? food or water?"

Comment: @johnny, JSON is an object. (Javascript **Object** Notation)

Comment: @simshaun thanks for correcting me.  I always thought of it that way because of the key:value combo like associative arrays.

Comment: Are people not noticing that this is a PHP question?  PHP arrays are basically javascript objects with ordering.  So they can work as either JSON objects or JSON arrays, or the mutant offspring of their prototypes.

Comment: @intuited: ah, that makes more sense. deleting my tongue-in-cheek answer and editing the question to make this more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better for your to use json because it can hold both it's own key:value object data but also arrays, again all in the same object.  Unless you are going to argue about sending arrays of json objects back to the client I suggest to you json is what you should use.

Answer (score 1):

On the page you link to he says:

> [arrays vs JSON is] Not a good comparison since JSON can have arrays inside of it

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the article, Arrays vs JSON is not a good comparison.  JSON can hold arrays, which are used frequently..